# Dynamically create tab with label device IP and pull the information from device to show up in display

Tags: django, ajax, tabs

I am trying to build an app which will do the authentication for the ARISTA or any other Device
IP address/username and password using eAPI json api. and once authenticated it will populate the device data into the new created dynamic tab.

I have created the app @ https://github.com/rakeshbitsindri/connect

what it is supposed to do is to do the Ajax call from the home.html to views.py for login once pressed the + button in the webpage, after successful authentication from DUT it will pull out the device info and add it in a dynamically created tab attached to the + button, this will be primary tab bar,

I will need the secondary tab bar as well, where i can show various information from device categorically and also apply config /modify some of the config of device.

The place where i am stuck is after pressing the + button the add_device page opens up, after putting device info the tab is not created, the device login info is correct but not sure how-to make it working

seems like the ajax call is either not working in my case, or ajax call is not returning the views.py function output. or may be the tab function itself is messed up.

Comment: Share what you tried, what's working/not working, expected results. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask